# how to pass a list parameter in a constructor in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

How can I add the List parameter in the insertionSort() contructor so that the run method doesnt have any parameters?

```
public class insertionSort extends Thread {

public insertionSort() {
  
}

// INSERTION SORT
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void run(List<T> list) {
    // sort the list using insertion sort
    for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
        T key = list.get(i);
        int j = i - 1;
        // move elements of list that are greater than key, to one position ahead of their current position
        while (j >= 0 && list.get(j).compareTo(key) > 0) {
            list.set(j + 1, list.get(j));
            j = j - 1;
        }
        // place element at its correct position
        list.set(j + 1, key);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you've created a **static** `run(List)`. This method is not related to the **instance** `run()` method, and therefore you are not taking advantage of extending `Thread`. You should make the *class* generic, and then add a `List` parameter to the constructor (which is no different than adding a parameter to a method). Then you save the list in a field that can be used later by the *instance* `run()` method.

```java
// Notice I changed the name to follow PascalCase, as is standard for classes in Java
public class InsertionSort<T extends Comparable<? super T>> extends Thread {

    private final List<T> list;

    public InsertionSort(List<T> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // perform insertion sort on 'list'
    }
}
```

And make sure you call `start()` if you want to start a new thread, not `run()`. For example:

```java
InsertionSort sort = new InsertionSort(theListInstance);
sort.start(); // start new thread, which calls 'run()' for you
```

Though I would strongly reconsider if you need to extend `Thread` here. Typically, the better approach is to implement `Runnable` instead of extending `Thread`. Then, if you need a new thread, you can just pass the `Runnable` to a `Thread`.

```java
public class InsertionSort<T extends Comparable<? super T>> implements Runnable {

    private final List<T> list;

    public InsertionSort(List<T> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // perform insertion sort on 'list'
    }
}
```

Then use it:

```java
InsertionSort sort = new InsertionSort(theListInstance);

// if you want to run the sort on the calling thread
sort.run();

// or if you want to run the sort on a new thread
Thread thread = new Thread(sort);
thread.start();
```